# Using NextJS's built in server vs Express

Tags: reactjs, express, next.js

I'm completely new to using Nextjs and want to learn it by building a project. I also want to use tRPC with it. I was reading the docs on using NextJS and tRPC and I learnt that there is a built in server in the /api under the pages folder. All the endpoints and server functions lives there.

I was wondering if I should be deploying all my server functions inside just the api folder or creating a separate custom Express server. It seems unscalable and weird to put all my server code into one client endpoint. To be clear I just want to do Authentication and CRUD functions but for future bigger projects, where such code would be split into microservices, would that then be deployed on a custom Express server instead?

Comment: FYI, `/api/x` and `/api/y` are not one endpoint.  Those are separate endpoints.

Comment: I don't think we can answer your question here.  It's an architectural question with a zillion possible solutions. many different opinions and narrowing down the solutions objectively depends upon lots of load, scale and design info that isn't disclosed or perhaps even known.